# Cannot read property 'type' of undefined. react-native typeorm

Tags: typescript, database, react-native, sqlite, typeorm

I use typeorm with sqlite3 in react-native app for android.
After create DataSource, i get error:

```
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined, js engine: hermes

ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method 
AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. 
Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, 
SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, 
GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
    A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is 
incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early 
initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes

ERROR  Invariant Violation: Failed to call into JavaScript module method 
AppRegistry.runApplication(). Module has not been registered as callable. 
Registered callable JavaScript modules (n = 11): Systrace, JSTimers, HeapCapture, 
SamplingProfiler, RCTLog, RCTDeviceEventEmitter, RCTNativeAppEventEmitter, 
GlobalPerformanceLogger, JSDevSupportModule, HMRClient, RCTEventEmitter.
    A frequent cause of the error is that the application entry file path is 
incorrect. This can also happen when the JS bundle is corrupt or there is an early 
initialization error when loading React Native., js engine: hermes
```

DataSource:

```
export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  type: "sqlite",
  database: "test",
  synchronize: false,
  logging: true,
  entities: models,
});
```

Enity:

```
@Entity()
export class Task {
  @PrimaryColumn('text')
  public id: string;

  @Column('text', { transformer: { from: JSON.parse, to:    JSON.stringify },})
  public taskStatus: TaskStatus;

  @Column('double')
  public distance: number;

  @Column('text')
  public taskType: string;

  @Column('int')
  public createDt: number;

  @Column('text', { transformer: { from: JSON.parse, to: JSON.stringify },})
  public object: TaskObject;
};
```

How to fix it?

After 5 hours of searching on the Internet, nothing came up.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Are you using expo? If that is the case your AppDataSource should be:
`const AppDataSource = new DataSource({ type: "expo", driver: require("expo-sqlite"), ...`